# Consulta mayor determinado por ID SQL

Tags: sql, codeigniter, subconsultas

Tengo una consulta que estoy haciendo, el hecho es que soy malísimo haciéndolo.

Mi tabla:

```
pagos_credito
```

Con sus columnas:

```
id_pagos_credito, contrato_id, fecha_adquisicion, costo_credito.
```

Intento que mediante “contrato_id” me tome el ÚLTIMO “id_pagos_credito” (hasta aquí todo bien con mi actual consulta) pero necesito que en base a lo anterior pueda mostrarme el registro de cualquiera de las otras columnas, ejemplo: el valor de “costo_credito”.
Lo que llevo:

```
SELECT MAX(id_pagos_credito) FROM pagos_credito WHERE contrato_id=1
```

| id_pagos_credito | contrato_id | fecha_adquisicion | costo_credito |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2018-04-11 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 2018-04-09 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 2018-04-08 | 20 |
| 4 | 2 | 2018-04-10 | 200 |

Quisiera que cuando ejecute la consulta me muestre
(costo_credito de contrato_id) de 2: 200
(fecha_adquisicion de contrato_id) de 1: 2018-04-08

Bueno, es básicamente seleccionar el **último valor (no el mayor)** de X tabla en base a su ID.
Espero hacerme entender, esto es la base para poder pasarlo a codeigniter mediante pase de parámetros. Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para encontrar el "último valor" ordenamos la columna con `ORDER BY id_pagos_credito` seguido de `ASC` o `DESC` para indicar la dirección del ordenamiento, y luego para limitar a un solo resultado `LIMIT 1`

Quedando como resultado:

```
SELECT id_pagos_credito, costo_credito
FROM pagos_credito
WHERE contrato_id=1
ORDER BY pagos_credito.id_pagos_credito DESC
LIMT 1;
```

Comment: Antes que nada, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer y responder esta pregunta. Hay un detalle en tu respuesta, fecha_adquisision no tiene nada que ver con el ordenamiento e intente tu consulta pero sigue sin devolverme el último valor (id_pagos_credito) de "contrato_I'd"

Comment: buenísimo vi la edición

Comment: Gracias de verdad